# UNIX TIMESTAMP GMT stored in sqlite in Integer, convert to local time zone

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, unix-timestamp, nstimeinterval

in my table in sqlite i have stored a date in timestamp in gmt time zone, in this way:

```
CREATE TABLE task (
id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
date INTEGER,
    name TEXT
);
```

when i query the database i want retrieve the date with the local time so:

```
NSTimeInterval now = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
```

the now timestamp is of my local time zone, so for example if it's possible i want do this:

```
SELECT id,date,name FROM task WHERE converttolocal(date) = now;
```

i want know if exist a function in sqlite like for instance `converttolocal` to automatically convert the timestamp...

**EDIT**

i found this:

```
strftime('%s',date, 'unixepoch', 'localtime')
```

but if for instance the date gmt in the database is: `1375660800` that is:

```
 GMT: Mon, 05 Aug 2013 00:00:00 GMT
```

after the function strftime the result is: `1375668000` that correspond at my local time:

```
 (CEST) Mine time zone: 05 agosto 2013 04:00:00
```

but i want that the result of the strftime function give me this: `1375653600` that is:

```
Mine time zone: 05 agosto 2013 00:00:00 CEST
```

Why doesn't give me this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert from a Unix timestamp to SQLite's default date format, use the `unixepoch` modifier.
To convert a time from UTC to local time, use the `localtime` modifier.
To convert from SQLite's default date format to a Unix timestamp, use [strftime](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) with the `%s` format:

```sql
SELECT id,date,name FROM task WHERE strftime('%s', date, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') = ?
```

It might be easier to use SQLite's built-in method to get the current time, which already is in UTC:

```sql
SELECT id,date,name FROM task WHERE datetime('%s', date, 'unixepoch') = datetime('now')
```

However, if you have only *dates*, you want to ignore the time portion.
In that case, use `date` instead of `datetime`:

```sql
SELECT id,date,name FROM task WHERE date('%s', date, 'unixepoch') = date('now')
```

Comment: take a look at my question, i have edited my question before you answer...and it's equal to your answer, but i think doesn't work...take a look at the edit...

Comment: Works for me. Please note that both the text date/time format and the Unix timestamp are *relative* to some time zone; the number `1375660800` always corresponds to `2013-08-05 00:00:00`, regardless of time zone.

Comment: if you put this 1375660800 in this strftime('%s',date, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') what result gives to you?

Comment: My time zone is UTC+2, so I get 1375668000. You must be careful to do neither too few nor too many time zone conversions.

Comment: so it's wrong, i live in italy, you in german (i see your profile) so we have the same timezone, if the date is 1375660800 and correspond to 2013-08-05 00:00:00, our 2013-08-05 00:00:00 is 1375653600 not 1375668000

Comment: Your comment is meaningless without specifying the time zone for each time value.

Comment: ok, i'm trying to explain it better, if in the sqlite db `date` is 1375660800 that correspond to: `Mon, 05 Aug 2013 00:00:00 GMT` i want that the function gives me the corresponding of the start of day of mine time zone (CEST) that is `1375653600` that correspond to `05 agosto 2013 00:00:00 CEST` but the function give to me and to you this value `1375668000` that is `05 agosto 2013 04:00:00 CEST`, and there are 4 hour of difference since the start of the day, i hope i'm explain better.

Comment: You are wrong. The start of the day is `1375660800` in *every* time zone, the same as the time `00:00:00` is the start of the day in every time zone.

Comment: ok, so i formulate better the question if i have `1375660800` in database, and if i do this: `NSTimeInterval todayTimeInterval = [[[NSDate date] dateAtStartOfDay] timeIntervalSince1970];` that is `1375653600`, i want do this: `SELECT id,name,date FROM task WHERE date <= ?` where `?` is `todayTimeInterval`, you understand now what is my problem? is for this that i want convert that value in sqlite query...

Comment: Your `dateAtStartOfDay` does not work correctly for Unix timestamps in GMT. Just compute `X - (X % 86400)` to get the correct start of the day, which you can then compare directly with the database values.

Comment: i now that the dateAtStartOfDay is my startOfdate of my timezone, because is that i want, i don't know how explain me better, i make just one try again: if i want that at midnight (start of day) reload all new task for that date, if i use the startOfDate at GMT that have this timestamp `1375660800` and correspond to this GMT: `Mon, 05 Aug 2013 00:00:00 GMT`, but in mine timezone correspond to this: `05 agosto 2013 02:00:00 CEST` so i doesn't have the refresh of the new task at the start of the day, but at `02:00:00`, i want refresh the that at my start of the day that is `1375653600`

Comment: So when you say "start of the day", you mean "start of the day in the current time zone"? In that case, just compare the value `1375653600` directly with the value in the database; neither value needs to be converted.

Comment: no i can't do that because `1375653600 != 1375660800`, so i never retrieve nothing, i maybe found a way to do it: `strftime('%s',1375653600, 'unixepoch', 'localtime')` give me `1375660800`, so i can do it in the reverse way...

Comment: But the value in the database (1375660800 in GMT) is *not* at the start of the day in your time zone, so is should not match.

Comment: i do this: SELECT id,name,date FROM task WHERE date = strftime('%s',?, 'unixepoch', 'localtime'); where ? is my startofday, seems work

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id,date,name FROM task WHERE datetime('date', 'unixepoch', 'localtime') = datetime('now','unixepoch');
```

This will work. But the left hand side value will never match with the right hand side and you will never retrieve a value, because you are capturing timestamps, by the time you compare, the timestamp value would have changed.

so , `SELECT id,date,name FROM task WHERE converttolocal(date) = now;` will never be true .

Comment: `datetime(...) = date(...)` will never match, and you are using a different `now` in the wrong time zone.